# Term for work outside your management chain?

Tags: career-development

I've been working a significant amount for another organization within my company outside of my direct management chain.  I've heard a term that summarizes that kind of situation, with a connotation of being vulnerable with respect to salary, advancement, retention because you're potentially diluting your value with your direct manager.

Thoughts?

Comment: What term have you heard? What have you googled so far? Work titles are quite company-specific... BTW Welcome to The Workplace, please read the [help/dont-ask] to familiarize yourself with the site and with what things are on-topic here.

Comment: Furthermore, what is your goal on asking about such term? What do you intend to do with that information?

Comment: Yea, I can't remember the term - hence the ask.  It was career advice from a senior person I respect that captured the situation and concern well.  I'm considering bringing this up with my manager, and likely with the other manager i'm working with and wondered if there was a common term for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 6):

This was new to me in my current job, but it's a legitimate word in the English language:

> Secondment = a period of time when an employee is sent to work somewhere else, to increase the number of workers , to replace other workers, or to exchange experience or skills (from the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/secondment))

It happens quite a bit in my current company - both to balance out the need to be somewhat fluid about getting stuff done, and also to give folks an opportunity to grow and experiment in their careers and in gaining subject matter expertise in diverse areas.

I've never really seen or treated this as a point of vulnerability, though.  IMO - it probably depends on the situation.  I've often worked for more than one organization, and taken pride in it - that my skills were unique and in demand enough to warrant some creativity in how I took on assignments - I found it useful to have a broad network and multiple supervisors happy with my work.

Certainly the usage I've seen of the word "secondment" is neutral or positive.  That it's done with the support of all involved, and wouldn't be something that would be done if the employee was a poor performer or otherwise in trouble.

Answer (score 2):

In some places this is a common occurrence in the company/organization, and the term I have seen used is matrixed.

An organization be be described as a matrixed organization. An employee is matrixed to the other team.

In some cases they are matrixed to the team for a single phase of the project, or to do a single task. In other cases they can be matrixed for months or years to another part of the organization.

Being a matrix employee has challenges. You report to multiple bosses. Sometimes you have to file double the number of status reports, and inform multiple people if you are taking leave.

Answer (score 1):

It absolutely can be a vulnerability in places which value command-and-control hierarchy and rigid metrics over cooperation and good-will. In the worst case scenario it means someone is taking your time and effort for their own benefit but at your expense (and that of your department). In that worst-case scenario, the term of art would be "getting used" (if someone put you up to it) or "going rogue" (if you're doing it on your own initiative).

If you do this make sure your boss and cohorts know the scope of what you're doing for the other department and that they're convinced it's worthwhile to the organization as a whole and to you and your team for the cross-functional experience and bridge-building. If everyone accepts what you're doing and you don't have to hide it, it may very well be a good thing. If you have to do it in secret, that's venturing into "getting used" or "going rogue".